# An explicit urlFetchWhitelist is required for all Google Workspace add-ons using UrlFetchApp error while deploying sheet add on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to deploy a google sheet add on (private add on.)
I am using moment js for calculating the date in my code.js file

My manifest looks like this

Manifest:
[image: Manifest]

When I go to deploy the add on I am getting the error

"An explicit urlFetchWhitelist is required for all Google Workspace add-ons using UrlFetchApp"

I went through the posts on stackoverflow for the same and i did three recommended changes

1. Added "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", to my oauthScopes [didn't work]
2. Installed a trigger and invoked the permission to fetch external request and it did not work.
3. Finally i tried to add a method to invoke the trigger on open as per [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers)

Still I am getting the same error when I go and click on deploy add on

urlFetchWhitelist error:
[image: urlFetchWhitelist error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to add a `urlFetchWhitelist` parameter to your manifest and include all urls that you wish to fetch in an array as its value.*

#### Example:

Say you have the line:

```
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://google.com")
```

in your code.

You will need to add this to the whitelist in the `appsscript.json` manifest file:

```
urlFetchWhitelist: ["https://google.com/"]
```

Things to note (from the documentation):

- Each prefix must be a valid URL.
- Each prefix must use `https://`, not `http://`.
- Each prefix must have a full domain.
- Each prefix must have a non-empty path. For example, `https://www.google.com/` is valid but `https://www.google.com` is not.
- You can use [wildcards](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests#using_wildcards) to match URL subdomain prefixes.
- A single * wildcard can be used in the [`addOns.common.openLinkUrlPrefixes`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#Common.FIELDS.openLinkUrlPrefixes) field to match all links, but this is not recommended as it can expose a user's data to risk and can prolong the [add-on review process](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-addon-review). Only use a wildcard if your add-on functionality requires it.

#### Update 2022-01-13:

As per information on [this Issue Tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192379454#comment3), only the domain/sub-domain needs to whitelisted for fetching.

For example, whitelisting:

```
"urlFetchWhitelist": ["https://myapp.com/"]
```

Will allow `UrlFetchApp` to connect to paths on that domain:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://myapp.com/getUser")
```

#### References:

- [Manifests for Google Workspace add-ons - Whitelisting URLs | Google Workspace add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests#whitelisting_urls)