# Google addon stopped working due to expired refresh token && url not being whitelisted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

Hello everyone recently my google calendar addon app has experienced a problem that the users could not login. From the stackdriver logs, it seems like the refresh token is expired. When I added the code "googleService.getLastError()" in my try catch block of "googleService.getAccessToken()". I got the error that says { https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token failed because the URL has not been whitelisted in the script manifest.] name: 'Exception' }. This is the url that attempts to get both access token and refresh token from google server. After I added this url to whitelist, my problem is resolved.

But what really confused me is that:

1. I talked to google support, they said that because the refresh token is expired, and when the app is calling above url, because it is not whitelisted, it rejects the request. Therefore my refresh token is not issued and not whitelisted exception is threw. But how does getAccessToken() throw expired token exception when that url is not whitelisted? Shouldn't the request got rejected directly by some other exceptions?
2. My app has been working for a half year without whitelisting that url and I haven't made any changes in past 6 months. Why does url not whitelisted issue only occur when my refresh token is expired? Or is there any relationship between refresh token expired and url not being whitelisted issue.

Answer (score 1):

### There has been a recent change in the security requirements for Add-ons

While until recently it worked without, as of now, all URLs to which your Add-on redirects must be whitelisted.

**Thus, previously working Add-ons using implementing not whitelisted urls are not working correctly anymore.**

- Many users are affected by this change.
- The only way to fix your Add-on is to whitelist the redirection urls and all other urls to which you perform a fetch request.
- Note that you are allowed to use wild cards to match subdomains.
- See [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests#whitelisting_urls) for more information about whitelisting.
- See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68191842/11599789) answer for more details on how to implement whitelisting into your Add-on.

Comment: Having this issue, do you know how to whitelist URLs such: "_https://my.domain.com/api/users/123123/profile", where 123123 is user_id. Till now, I was using "_https://my.domain.com/*" but seems that it is no longer accepted.